# (x86) Accessing dseg variables

Tags: assembly, x86

I am writing an assembly code that requires me to access values of an array defined in my `dseg`. For example:

```
mov si, 5
mov al, x[si+1]
```

This works perfectly when compiled in `TASM` and does not throw any error back. Yet, when I try this piece of code:

```
mov si, 5
mov x[si], x[si-1]
```

I get an error telling me that i'm doing an `Illegal memory reference`. Am I doing something wrong? Is there an elegant way around this without moving values around in other registries and subtracting 1 from them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one shouldn't assemble either, because x86 `mov` instruction simply doesn't take two memory operands. It's a bug in tasm if it accepts that. Check what code it created using a disassembler. You have to go through a register.

Edit: in the original question the first version was `mov x[si], x[si+1]`, that's what my comment referred to.

Comment: Sorry, i had a typo.. Perhaps that's the problem? I'll check it, hold it for a second. :)